# How do I obtain the delta between two dates?

Tags: python, django

I've been searching around before asking this.

I have Django template, which inputs a water account number, a beginning date, and an ending date. The dates define a search range, and are in mm/dd/yyyy format.

I'd like to convert these dates into a Python format, so I can find the difference between them. I'm aware of date and datetime objects, and I know I can parse -- for example -- 05/01/2012 -- and create a date object from that.

However, I'm interested in a better way to this, like converting the "05/01/2012" directly for start and end date range values, and then taking the delta between those Python date objects.

Thank you.

Edit:
This is what I'm using to calculate the delta:

```
d1 and d2 are date strings in the form: mm/dd/yyyy.
def time_delta(d1, d2):
    dd1   = datetime.strptime(d1, "%m/%d/%Y").date()
    dd2   = datetime.strptime(d2, "%m/%d/%Y").date()
    delta = dd2 - dd1
    return delta.days
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
from datetime import *
d1 = datetime.strptime('05/01/2012', "%d/%m/%Y").date()
d2 = datetime.strptime('06/01/2012', "%d/%m/%Y").date()
delta = d2 - d1
print(delta.days)
```

Comment: Am getting this error: AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime' Would you also consider reformatting this perhaps with a blank line in between the two dates, so it's all on one line?

Comment: import datetime (not from datetime import datetime).

Comment: I've tried d1 = datetime.strptime('05/01/2012', "%d/%m/%Y").date()
d2 = datetime.strptime('06/01/2012', "%d/%m/%Y").date()
d2 - d1 and it's not yielding an integer difference.

Comment: I have improved the answer. You can also get the delta in days via delta.days

Comment: @jterrace If you fix your format string to "%m/%d/%Y", you'll have the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using Django forms for this kind of thing. If you use date fields, then `start_date` and `end_date` will be Python date objects when you you fetch them out of the form's cleaned data dictionary.

If you haven't used Django forms before, then I recommend that you read through the [forms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#working-with-forms). Here's a couple of snippets as a hint.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField()
    end_date = forms.DateField()
    # other fields e.g. water account number

# in your view
if request.method == "POST":
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        start_date = form.cleaned_data['start_date']
        end_date = form.cleaned_data['end_date']
        delta = end_date - start_date
        # do anything else you need to do
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll think about this for the future. Quick question, though. Are these classes defined in views.py?

Comment: You can define the form class in the `views.py`. In many apps, including the Django admin, the forms are defined in `forms.py`, when imported in the view: `from myapp.forms import MyForm`

Comment: I've got some cleanup to perform on this site this summer. It's two years old and leveraged a lot of command line code, so the application did not take full advantage of Django. I'm a group of one, so some things get short-cuts. Again, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. `strptime` is a pragmatic solution for today, and when you get around to rewriting the view, you can use forms then :)

Answer (score 1):

The [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) module is really nice for parsing dates:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse("05/01/2012") - parse("04/01/2012")
datetime.timedelta(30)
```

Comment: For python 2.X, you want to install ``python-dateutil==1.5``, otherwise just ``python-dateutil`` for python 3.X